# Keeping databases structure in sync

Tags: sql-server

Lets pretend we have several similar websites each focussing on a separate country. We want to have the same code and same SQL Server database structures but the content of each database is different.

Is there an easy way of keeping the databases structurally in sync - adding a column to one will result in it being added to all?

Basically have a group of databases that column/table changes/additions/edits are propagated through?

Comment: Sounds like you shouldn't be using separate databases for each one. Though, if you do need separate databases, then this should be part of the deployment scripts you produce; which ensures that it updates all the databases you need it to. There is no magic "`ALTER PROCEDURE {Database List}.dbo...`" syntax though.

Comment: Perhaps, instead, you should be looking at schema comparison tools and using those to alert you of "drifts" between a database and the others; then you know that if one database has "drifted" you can review your deployment mechanism(s) to see why that database wasn't included.

Comment: Useful suggestions require context. It would help to know why this is such an issue that it requires some sort of automation. Otherwise, standard development and release practices should make this a trivial exercise. Perhaps that is the issue? Do you have standard procedures for making database changes (including validation, documentation, and addition to disaster recovery plans)? Is your schema in source control?

Comment: As an example you may wish to use a SQL Server Database Project, and deploy from this single version to your target database.